# What conditions would make you feel comfortable inputting your SSN?

Tags: email, account-security

I am doing some analogous research on data collection and was curious if a company followed up with you asking for your SSN what would be the safest / most convenient way to send it to them.

Some thoughts I had were

- Email with secure link to a form on the company's webpage
- Direct number for someone who will pick up immediately, no automated system or waiting
- A form to select the best time to call you back
- Somewhere on the companies phone app

For the sake of argument lets just say it is required by the government to submit it.

Comment: The literal (but likely off of intended topic) answer to "Which conditions" is a legal/business environment where it's just an identifying number and not a secret whose disclosure carries financial risks. Like almost everywhere outside USA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A previously established trusted channel

In order for a channel to be *considered* safe, the priority is the user's feeling of trust, it's not sufficient for it to simply *be* safe. It also needs to be convenient, unless the user is absolutely desperate and locked in.

This pretty much means that you need to reuse a channel that the user already knows and trusts without creating or explaining something new.

The following avenues come to mind:

- If all the users have existing accounts in your web system, then submitting SSN in it is just as OK as any other way - they need to trust you anyways, but a proper https website will feel adequate. It may be a bonus if the submitted SSN is not visibly stored, if their user profile only shows a checkbox "Yes, you've submitted your SSN, we've stowed it away someplace secure".
- If the users have your mobile application, then they will probably feel secure inputting the data there, since there are no reasonable indicators for them to feel that your approach is less secure than e.g. their email on that device. It's your job to ensure that the submission actually is secure, but it doesn't influence the user impressions directly.

The suggested ways to submit over the phone seem less appropriate to me. Telling your data to an operator (likely minimum wage, possibly offshore) over the phone by itself feels a security risk; it could be argued that however your SSN gets there, those employees shouldn't have access to see it. However, there will be a segment of users, e.g. elderly people, who will prefer this channel anyway to anything digital.

Email with a secure link seems to be the worst option. While *your* email with that link may be secure, there is no easy way to distinguish that from a phishing operation, so such emails will be (and should be!) mistrusted by definition. The proper way would be an email that informs them to log in to your site in the *usual way*, and have a personal notification *on your site* take them to appropriate form when/if they log in.

Comment: you hit on a lot of issues we were discussing, and we actually do need this or the IRS will take their refund. If you had to sign up with us through a third party like a travel agent would you feel comfortable giving that third party your information later? We are trying to find a way to give the in person / talking to a personal touch if desired. I agree  that email route could seem like it is phishing, would it be weird to throw an email tracker in there so we can tell who has actually opened the email so we know who we need to send snail mail to? Trying to ride that line of trust